# Kendo Linear Guage with logarithmic scale

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts, kendo-chart

I need to represent a Non-linear or large scale of values in Kendo Linear Gauge chart & highlight different range of values & mark multiple over the scale. Challenge is given small size of chart, large range or value doesn't render/look good.

http://dojo.telerik.com/@kk8322/ULokuFuZ

I am ready to switch to any other javascript chart library (preferably Highcharts/Kendo charts) for getting this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the width of the gauge area. [API Reference for it.](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/dataviz/ui/lineargauge/configuration/gaugearea.width)

```
<script>
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    $("#gauge").kendoLinearGauge({                        
                 gaugeArea:{
                     width:500
                 },         
                 pointer: [{
                    value: 670000,
                    shape: "arrow",
                    color: "black"
                }, {
                    value: 480000,
                    color: "blue",
                    shape: "arrow"
                }, {
                    value: 570000,
                  size: 15,
                    color: "blue",
                    shape: "arrow"
                }],

                        scale: {
                            min: 470000,
                            max: 770000,
                            vertical: false,
                            ranges: [{
                                    from: 470000,
                                    to: 470500,
                                    color: "#c20000"
                                },{
                                    from: 470500,
                                    to: 471000,
                                    color: "yellow"
                                }, {
                                    from: 771500,
                                    to: 770500,
                                    color: "yellow"
                                }, {
                                    from: 770500,
                                    to: 770000,
                                    color: "#c20000"
                                }]
                        }
                    });
                });
            </script>
```